# Firebase deploy old version somehow (angular 6)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed a version of my site on firebase via console.

Then I did a minor change - deleted a console.log() - but somehow it didn't change  and I still get the console.log() ...

I rebuild it with no problems and deployed it again. It also was uploaded on firebase successfully...

Does anyone have a clue what could be the cause?

edit:
when I test it with

> firebase serve

it works how it should... -.-

Comment: Probably a cache update problem. Either clear the cache or serve your app again. Normally serve command should fire an update when a change is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Firebase Hosting sets cache headers for one hour (two hours for images). If you want want different caching behavior you can [configure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers) shorter or longer in `firebase.json`.

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "headers": [{
            "source": "**",
            "headers": [{
                "key": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "max-age=300"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay actually it takes some time to get uploaded and shown. Everything works fine now.

Thought it would be set immediately but it takes around 45mins